# Ubuntu 18.04 Freezes screen and hangs on shutdown and restart what can be done?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, shutdown, ssd, msi

I have done a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 on my new MSI GL63RD Laptop. My laptop's configuration is 8 GB RAM, NVIDIA GEForce GTX 1050Ti(4 GB), and 128 GB SSD. I have tried almost every fix available on the forums, like updating grub with acpi force and alternative shutdown options but, none of them work. I consider this as a highly important issue since power off/restart are basic operations for an OS.  The version works fine with other laptops with lower version of GPUs. Is there any special update I should make based on the configuration I have?  Is this something related to the GPU/SSD? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm in the same situation so +1 for the question.
I've installed 18.04.1 and was able to boot into it, then I've updated the apps, used it without any restart for 1 day and now after I've closed it, it won't boot up anymore.
I didn't change/update my drivers.
My laptop also has an Nvidia GTX1060 and a 512 GB NVME SSD.
Although I should mention this is the first time I'm actually able to boot into Ubuntu, I've tried previous versions and all of them hang on the first boot after install.